# Interaction between 2 UVM registers

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

I trying implement UVM RAL for my project, and now faced with problem. For example I have 2 registers - reg A and reg B. I create classes for both, but from device spec value in field A.field1 mapping from B.field2. How I can implement this in UVM RAL.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking to use aliased registers. The concept is described in the uvm user guide in section 5.7.3 .(page 114 ) 
http://accellera.org/images/downloads/standards/uvm/uvm_users_guide_1.1.pdf

The example in the umm user guide uses a couple of concepts and the same concept can be used to generate the aliasing for the A.field1 and B.field2.

- A call back mechanism
  A call back can be set up for the post predict function of the reg B.field2 . Every time ,after the value of B.field2 changes the post-predict function is triggered. In the post predict function the field value of register A ( A.field1) is also updated [ by calling the field1.predict ]reflecting the change/linkage. ( assuming A.field1 is dependent/alias of B.field2)
- wrapper class
  Create a wrapper class which will connect the fields from both these registers (A & B - A.field1 to B.field2) and instantiate the wrapper class. The wrapper class also registers the callback for register B field2. If the register model is auto generated the wrapper class can be  instanced outside the register model , else like in the example inside the model itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a callback mechanism, “**`uvm_reg_cbs`**” specifically as per your requirement. In this class, there are predefined functions like pre_write() , post_write() , post_predict() etc. which provide the flexibility in interdependency between registers.

You can extend your register (Reg A) class with "uvm_reg_cbs" and register this callback with another register (Reg B).